# How to plot percentage of NaN in pandas data frame?

Tags: python, dataframe, plot, nan, percentage

I'd like someone to help me plot the NaN percentage of pandas data frame. I calculated percentage using this code.

```
per_1 = df_1.isna().mean().round(4) * 100
```

It gave me this result.

```
HR              7.94
O2Sat          10.36
Temp           66.06
SBP            15.20
MAP             9.17
Age             0.00
Gender          0.00
ICULOS          0.00
SepsisLabel     0.00
Patient_iD      0.00
```

Now, I want to plot the percentage along with the column names of data frame. Can anyone help me?

Regards.

---

Updated: The graph looks like this. How to beautify this in order to see the column name clearly?

[image: Graph]

Also, is it possible to show the percentage on each bar like shown in this below graph?

[image: percentage]

---

Update: The only issue is with HR percentage:

[image: pic]

Comment: Does the answer posted below solve your problem?

Comment: Hi. Yes it did. But I am facing an issue. Those columns with ZERO nan value are also in graph but graph is not looking good.

Comment: Updated my question. How to adjust the column names so it can be seen clearly?

Comment: Hi, I have updated the solution. Please have a look if that solves your problem.

Comment: Hi.. Thanks a lot :) It did solved the problem. However I faced the issue with HR percentage. See the question.

Comment: Check the new update to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can plot a barplot using the following code snippet::

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.bar(per_1.keys(), per_1.values)
plt.show()
```

Sample output:

[image]

### UPDATE:

As per your update to the question, here is a solution that retains only columns having percentage greater than zero. Also the plot has been beautified as requested with values displayed over each bar.

```
f, ax = plt.subplots()

for i,item in enumerate(zip(per_1.keys(),per_1.values)):
    if (item[1] > 0):
        ax.bar(item[0], item[1], label = item[0])
        ax.text(i - 0.25, item[1] + 1.5 , str(item[1]))

ax.set_xticklabels([]) 
ax.set_xticks([]) 
plt.ylim(0,80)
plt.ylabel('Percentage')
plt.xlabel('Columns')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Sample Output:

[image]

### UPDATE 2:

To round the decimals to two decimal places, replace this line in the earlier code:

`ax.text(i - 0.25, item[1] + 1.5 , str(np.round(item[1],2)))`

You will need to import numpy if not already done:
`import numpy as np`

Comment: Glad that it worked for you. I'd appreciate if you could then accept the answer (tick mark below the voting section) to acknowledge it as the solution.

Comment: Done :) I am new to this website so IDK how this works. BTW Thanks once again :)